# How to clear specific cookies using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, flask

I create cookies with Java Script and refresh the page like so...

```
document.cookie = "driveValue=" + "Runner"
document.cookie = "cachedOffset=" + "56"
location.reload()
```

I then retrieve a dictionary of the cookies with Python Flask showed below...

```
@app.route('/config', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def config():
cookie = request.cookies
cookieItems = cookie.items()
```

Now that I have a dictionary mapping the name to the values, i want to clear those specific cookies (or change the value to an empty string). How do I go about doing this. So far, I have tried this example listed below...

```
resp = make_response(render_template('master.html', form=form, cookieItems=cookieItems)
resp.set_cookie("cachedOffset", "", expires=0)
resp.set_cookie("driveValue", "", expires=0)
return resp
```

I thought this would work but it is not changing any of the cookies to an empty space.

Here is where the cookies are located that I would like to change. [image]

Comment: You forget that cookies stored by domain try to set the cookie from the same domain resp.set_cookie("cacheValue", "", domain="same domain set by the client")

Comment: I changed each of the set_cookie functions to `resp.set_cookie("cachedOffset", "", domain="localhost")` . I based this off the cookies in Google inspector but it still is not clearing them. The image is now attached.

Comment: Do you see that the return cookie on the client has beed changed?

Comment: It has not changed anything. The values have not been set to `""`.

Comment: On js side use cookie.setDomain('127.0.0.1') and in the server side as the domain for the set cookie function

Comment: Still nothing. I don't think that would make a difference anyway if the domain is already set to localhost in the inspector. It is very strange that I am able to retrieve these cookies, but not modify the cookies in any way.

Comment: Try this changing flask app.run('localhost'), and the without changing the js cookie to 127.0.0.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254013/why-does-the-session-cookie-work-when-serving-from-a-domain-but-not-when-using-a