# Flask Form is Validated but Login Code Block is not being Run

Tags: python, authentication, validation, flask, web

Within the Flask app, there is a route for login. This route will set form = LoginForm() which is a separate class. Once the form is validated, the username and password hash are checked and flask login is used to log in the user. It is then supposed to Flash a success message, but I am not getting any success or failure message Flash.

**User Class**

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, user_data):
        self.id = str(user_data['id'])
        self.first_name = str(user_data['first_name'])
        self.last_name = str(user_data['last_name'])
        self.username = str(user_data['username'])
        self.email = str(user_data['email'])
        self.password = str(user_data['password'])
```

**User Loader**

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user_data = users_collection.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(user_id)})
    return User(user_data) if user_data else None
```

**Login Class**

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.DataRequired()])
    password = StringField('Password', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

**Login Route**

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('form validated')
        user_data = users_collection.find_one({'username': form.username.data})
        if user_data and check_password_hash(user_data['password'], form.password.data):
            print("login good")
            user = User(user_data)
            login_user(user)
            flash('Login Successful.', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            flash("Login Failed", 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', form = form)
```

**Login HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Kodinger">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body class="my-login-page">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">pyTicket</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <section class="h-100">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center h-100">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="card fat">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Login</h4>
                            <form method="POST" class="my-login-validation" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                                    {{ form.username }}

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    {{ form.password }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group m-0">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block", value="Login">
                                        Login
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-4 text-center">
                                    Don't have an account? <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Create One</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Imports (If Necessary)**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import redirect
from flask import url_for
from flask import flash
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms import PasswordField
from wtforms import validators
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_login import login_user
from flask_login import logout_user
from flask_login import login_required
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from bson import ObjectId
import pymongo
import uuid
```

Comment: You need to update the templates of `dashboard` route and `login` route to show the flash messages. This answer shows a full example of user registration process with message flashing https://stackoverflow.com/a/77701881/3129414